# How do I assign an identifier to a Java object

Tags: java, angularjs, object

I have the following situation. In my Java back end I collect some data from a service, I create data objects out of it and pass that to my Angular front end. Then a user might choose do something with one of the objects and sends its changed state to the back end. The back end collects the same data again from the service and now I have to identify which object the user choose. I want to do this by creating a common identifier. And here comes my question: how can I best generate the identifier?

First I did the following:

- Get data from service
- Assign an increasing integer in for-loop

However, I ran into the following problem. The second time the service is called, the same data might return but in a different order. So my first thought was to order the collected data first and then assign the integer. But ordering this data is quite a pain so I thought of something else:

- Take the two fields of the data object that makes it unique
- Make a string out of those fields and concatenate
- Do a .hashCode() on the result

This creates an int that can't be traced back to the original data. That's exactly what I want, but now for the funny part. The hashCodes can collide. My fear is that in very, very rare cases the hashCode will be the same, even though the original string was different!

Is my fear grounded? And how can I compose a better id?

Comment: It's very hard to think about all of this in the abstract. It would make it much easier to help you if you'd make everything concrete. Are those two string fields part of what you're returning? If so, don't they form an identifier on their own? Can't you order by them, if you want to maintain a stable ordering?

Comment: (And no, using `hashCode()` for this purpose is pretty much *never* a good idea.)

Comment: What is format of data you get from service (`Java back end I collect some data from a service`)? Does it have any identifier? Can you add fields to it?

Comment: _"This creates an int that can't be traced back to the original data. That's exactly what I want"_ Why do you want that?

Comment: I don't understand why if you have two fields that when combined act as a unique identifier how you could get hash codes that collide, also if you have two such fields why not just use them as the Identifier directly to compare objects ?

Comment: The best solution would be a unique ID for each record.

Comment: @Henry if he can alter the service that is giving him the data then yes.

Comment: @user1450877 "how you could get hash codes that collide" - Two different values of for example a string can have the same hashcode. That's a collision. If you can have collisions on each of two strings, then you can have collisions on the concatenation of the two, don't you? That's the nature of the hash function.